# Software Insallation errors

Tags: package-management

I have been trying to install `ghdl` and `gtkwave` but couldn't so far.

Here is what I have been getting:

```
sudo apt-get install ghdl

Reading package lists... Done 

Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done

Package ghdl is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing,has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
```

Comment: Have you recently or removed added any ppa's? Run `sudo apt-get update` and see if the problem still occurss

Comment: ghdl you can try from https://theintobooks.wordpress.com/2016/08/24/installing-ghdl-from-source-on-ubuntu-16-04/  according to the actual website, it has not been updated since 2010.  But you should be able to install `gtkwave` Bnormally through `sudo apt-get install gtkwave`

Answer (score 2):

I used [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chGoodchild/setup_scripts/master/ghdl.sh) to install it directly from the github repository, which was last updated yesterday...

```
#!/bin/bash

# First get the file from github
git clone https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl
cd ghdl
./configure --prefix=/usr/local
#In case you get the error "Sorry, you need GNAT to build GHDL. See the README" do `sudo apt install gnat`

# fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory include <zlib.h>
sudo apt-get -y install libz-dev

make
make install
sudo apt-get -y install gtkwave

# Usage instructions:
printf "\n\n\nUsage instructions:\n"
wget -qO- https://github.com/chGoodchild/setup_scripts/raw/master/using_ghdl.sh
```

You can execute the script by copying the following commands into your terminal:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/chGoodchild/setup_scripts/master/ghdl.sh
chmod +x ghdl.sh
sudo ./ghdl.sh
```